# Irrelevant couplings in string theory

Tags: string-theory, field-theory, renormalization

Considering a scalar for simplicity, imagine a potential $V=\sum_n\lambda_n\phi^n$. For $n$ sufficiently large that $\lambda_n$ has negative energy dimension, the $\phi^n$ term is negligible at energies $\ll\Lambda$, which is why $\lambda_n$ is called an irrelevant coupling. A theory in which only finitely many terms are relevant or marginal can typically be renormalised, because it only has finitely many coupling parameters to specify.

A high-energy theory should finitely specify irrelevant $\lambda_n$, e.g. with a recursion relation. How, if at all, does superstring/M-theory do this?

Comment: String theory has no analogue to your potential, really, so I don't understand the question. The only parameter we can "adjust" in this sense in string theory itself is the string tension.

Comment: @ACuriousMind True, there's not much the theory leaves unspecified - the tension, the Calabi-Yau manifold, that's about it. But can we prove enough about the resulting field theories that relations between couplings emerge from it?

Comment: If you compactify, the coupling constants of the resulting low-energy effective QFT will be controlled by the geometric properties of the compacification manifold (e.g. the Kähler moduli of a Calabi-Yau). But note that this is just an *effective* theory with no need to be renormalizable (since the true high energy theory is string theory, not a QFT), so your question about relevant/marginal/irrelevant terms is beside the point. (If that is what you're looking for as an answer, I will add it as an answer)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I know that, but what I'm looking for is a rearrangement of the determination by geometry into a relation between the couplings, if one exists; or is each due to a different degree of freedom in the manifold?